# с++ регулярное выражение для char

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, оптимизация, производительность

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно проверить содержит ли переменная `char *hBuff` 11ти значное число?

Comment: Именно строго 11-значное число, или среди прочего 11-значное число? Целое число?

Comment: строго 11 значное число

Comment: Я бы просто проверял, что там либо 11 цифр, за которыми идет нулевой символ, либо `-`, за которым идут те же 11 цифр. Мне кажется, что это будет быстрее, чем использовать тяжелую артиллерию регулярных выражений...

Answer (score 4):

А заинтересовало, насколько и в самом деле регулярные выражения - из пушки по воробьям...

Вот две функции для выполнения запрашиваемой проверки...
*Кстати, молодой человек! это ответ и на ваш вопрос тоже... (с) Анекдот*

```
regex rg("-{0,1}\\d{11}");

inline int match_r(const char * s)
{
    return regex_match(s,rg);
}

inline int match_p(const char * s)
{
    if (*s == '-') ++s;
    for(int i = 0; i < 11 ; ++i)
        if (!isdigit(*s++)) return 0;
    return *s == 0;
}
```

Генерирую 2 миллиона строк - из них 1 миллион верных, и 1 миллион неверных - и напускаю эти функции. Полная программа - [здесь](https://ideone.com/EeH69g) или [здесь](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/regexp_vs_code.cpp).

На ideone соотношение времен в 27 раз не в пользу регулярных выражений. На моей машине с VC++ 2019 результат еще более удручающий - простой код быстрее в 98 раз...

Словом, пользуясь военной терминологией, применение гаубицы `regexp` оправдано только для особо укрепленных дотов :)

Comment: Не стоит обижать такую **надежную** (в отличии от regexp-ов) штуку, как гаубица

Comment: @avp Ну, я просто вначале высказался, что это из пушки по воробьям. Вот и навеяло :)

Comment: Это я понял. Просто так иносказательно выразился о сложности тестирования программ с регулярками. Со сложной регуляркой  никогда  до конца не уверен, что она всегда работает как задумано

Comment: @avp И это тоже есть... :)